# ListView SetAdapter NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, adapter, android-context

I can't find out why NPE takes place here.  Spent a lot of time trying to figure this out. Using logs I've found where comes the crash (Records.class...scroll down). Also I give every code-file if it's needed. I found out that it's NOT context is null.

**Records.class**

```
  package com.wordpress.jimmaru.tutorial.SimpleGame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Records extends Activity{

    private Score_DS ds=new Score_DS(this);
    Data_LV[] data;
    String[] name,score;
    ListView lvrecords;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // если хотим, чтобы приложение постоянно имело портретную ориентацию
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            // если хотим, чтобы приложение было полноэкранным
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            // и без заголовка
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.records);
            //setContentView(new GameView(this,null));

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

         lvrecords=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        Recfill();


      }

    public void Recfill()
    {ds.open();
    Log.d("Pidar","ds.open");
    name=ds.curspinner("Records","Player_Name");
    score=ds.curspinner("Records","Player_Score");
    Log.d("Pidar","curspinner");
    ds.close();
    Log.d("Pidar","ds.close");
    int i=0;
    if (score.length>0){
    data=new Data_LV[score.length];
    Log.d("Pidar","data new");
    while (i<score.length) {Log.d("Pidar","cikl "+i);
        data[i]=new Data_LV();
        Log.d("Pidar","data[i] new");
        data[i].id=Integer.toString(i+1);
        data[i].name=name[i];
        data[i].score=score[i];

        i++;
    }
    Log.d("Pidar","nachalo adaptera");
    LV_Adapter adapter = new LV_Adapter(this, R.layout.item, data);

    **lvrecords.setAdapter(adapter);** //This line doesn't execute
    }
    else
    { Toast.makeText(this, "Записей нет", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}   
    }
}
```

**records.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LV_Adapter**

```
package com.wordpress.jimmaru.tutorial.SimpleGame;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class LV_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data_LV> {
    public LV_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Data_LV[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    public LV_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Data_LV> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pl_id);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pl_name);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pl_score);

        Data_LV d = getItem(position);
        t1.setText(d.id);
        t2.setText(d.name);
        t3.setText(d.score);


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Data_LV**

```
package com.wordpress.jimmaru.tutorial.SimpleGame;

public class Data_LV {
String id;
String name;
String score;
}
```

Log error
[image]

**UPD** I Found out that context is not null. Using logs I got context=android.app.Application@4266f9e0.. So it's not context problem. Data is filled too. So maybe the problem in R.layout.item?)

Comment: What is it in line 76 of Records.java?

Comment: there comes lvrecords.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Sometimes R file will not be generated correctly. Try cleaning your project and run again.

Comment: Tried now. It didn't help(

Comment: well, obviously `lvrecords` is null by the time you trying to use it. Can you verify that ? I like your comments in russian btw : )

Comment: I think the most likely cause of your problem is the stale generated R.java files, which causes `findViewById(R.id.listView1)` return `null`. If you are on Eclipse do `Project -> Clean`, that should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out what was the problem. Thanks to all who helped, The problem was in lvrecords itself. It was null. And here's why.
In my project I have 2 layout folders - for portrait and landscape mode. In this app I never use portrait mode. And some xml files of portrait view are just empty... And shame on me, but this worked, cause I limited my app for only using landscape mode. I actually forgot that these files are empty, like records.xml. And I thought that Eclipse would take only landscape mode xml files, like it did all the time, but here it didn't. So when I added listview to records.xml in portrait folder, it worked. 
I apologize cause no one except me could know this. Even I forgot about this.

Comment: Stupidly, I made the same mistake! I referred to two xml layout files but I had only actually put a ListView in one of them!

Comment: And, thanks to you, now I can leave comments) Thank you

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer by clicking on the green tick.